# how to find date after 3 days

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I Have Current date. Ho to find Date After 3 Days. I am Using CodeIgniter My Controller is -

```
public function index()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $Curr_Date = date('Y/m/d');
    $today_dt = new DateTime($Curr_Date);
}
```

Comment: Checkout the [modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method of DateTime.

Comment: I disagree on the duplicate, as that thread is over 6 years old and demonstrates outdated methods. Only at the very bottom do you find the recommended way of doing it, namely with DateTime's `add()` method.

Comment: Sorry Shaktimaan.

Answer (score 1):

```
$newDate = new DateTime(strtotime("+3 days"));
```

i think this may help you...

Comment: see edited text,not the first text i write.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straight forward. You can do this using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
public function index()
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $today_dt = new DateTime();
    $in3days = new DateTime();
    $in3days->add(new DateTimeInterval("PD3"));
}
```

or you can use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$in3days = new DateTime(strtotime("+3 days"));
```